# Placing two rows on the same line with bootstrap elements

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, jsx

I would like to display two rows (`tr`) on the same line with equal width. I tried adding `col-sm-6` to the `td`s, but it's the `tr`s are getting displayed on two separate lines. Here's the html:

```
<div className="jumbotron col-sm-12 text-left row">
                    <div className="panel panel-info">
                        <div className="panel-heading">
                            HEADER
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <table className="table table-bordered table-condensed table-responsive">
                        <tbody>
                             <tr>
                                <td className="col-sm-6 col-centered leftCol">
                                    <div>
                                        {"hello1"}
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td className="col-sm-6 col-centered rightCol">
                                    <div>
                                        {'hello2'}
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: just add css to it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make Bootstrap columns all the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to insert class `col-sm-6` for tr tags if you want them on same line.

Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nnoLbo2d/) of your code

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div className="jumbotron col-sm-12 text-left row">
  <div className="panel panel-info">
    <div className="panel-heading">
      HEADER
    </div>
  </div>

  <table className="table table-bordered table-condensed table-responsive">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="col-sm-6">
        <td className="col-centered leftCol">
          <div>
            {"hello1"}
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="col-sm-6">
        <td className="col-centered rightCol">
          <div>
            {'hello2'}
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: If code here is not running, it could be due to failure to load bootstrap files. Try from fiddle

Comment: the 2 rows are being displayed correctly now, but the `td`'s width are incorrect.  Id like the `td`s to span throught the row they're in

Comment: You can add class="row" to tbody tag

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <div className="jumbotron col-sm-12 text-left row">
                        <div className="panel panel-info">
                            <div className="panel-heading">
                                HEADER
                            </div>
                        </div>
    
                        <table className="table table-bordered table-condensed table-responsive">
                        <tbody>
                             <tr>
                                <td className="col-sm-6 col-centered leftCol">
                                    <div>
                                        {"hello1"}
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td className="col-sm-6 col-centered rightCol">
                                    <div>
                                        {'hello2'}
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div className="jumbotron col-sm-12 text-left row">
                    <div className="panel panel-info">
                        <div className="panel-heading">
                            HEADER
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <table className="table table-bordered table-condensed table-responsive">
                        <tbody>
                             <tr>
                                <td className="col-sm-6 col-centered leftCol" style="height: 200px;">
                                    <div>
                                        {"hello1"}
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td className="col-sm-6 col-centered rightCol" style="height: 200px;">
                                    <div>
                                        {'hello2'}
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Adding style will do it.